How to run py_binary from bazel actions?
I was trying to model examples I found here to create a rule that executes a python script on input files:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/blob/main/rules/generating_code/gen/enum_maker.bzl
I have this implementation:
def _matchcompiler_impl(ctx):
    deps      = _get_transitive_deps(ctx.attr.srcs, ctx.attr.deps)
    write_dir = ctx.attr.write_dir
    prefix    = ctx.attr.prefix 
    args      = ctx.actions.args()
    outputs   = []
    raw_files = []
    
    for dep in deps.to_list():
        outputs.append(ctx.actions.declare_file("{}/{}{}".format(write_dir, prefix, dep.basename)))

    args.add("--read-dir=lib")
    args.add("--write-dir={}".format(write_dir))
    args.add_all(raw_files)

    ctx.actions.run(
        inputs     = deps,
        outputs    = outputs,
        arguments  = [args],
        executable = ctx.executable.tool,
        progress_message = "Doing Something"
    )

    print("Made it here.")

matchcompiler = rule(
    implementation = _matchcompiler_impl,
    attrs = {
        "srcs":attr.label_list(allow_files = [".cpp"]),
        "deps":attr.label_list(
            aspects=[cc_srcs_aspect],
            providers=[CcInfo]
        ),
        "tool":attr.label(
            default     = Label(":matchcompiler"), # default pybinary executable
            executable  = True, # must be an executable
            allow_files = True,
            cfg         = "exec" # for the execution platform
        ),
        "verify":attr.bool(
            doc = "Verify compiled matches against on the fly parser, slow"
        ),
        "show_skipped":attr.bool(
            doc = "show skipped (non-static) patterns"
        ),
        "read_dir":attr.string(
            default="lib"
        ),
        "write_dir":attr.string(
            default="build"
        ),
        "prefix":attr.string(),
        "line":attr.bool(
            default=False
        )
    },
)

and in my build file:
py_binary(
    name = "matchcompiler",
    srcs = [
        "tools/matchcompiler.py"
    ],
    main = "tools/matchcompiler.py"
)

cc_library(
    name = "cppcheck",
    hdrs = glob(["lib/*.h"], allow_empty = False),
    srcs = glob(["lib/*.cpp"], allow_empty = False),
)

matchcompiler(
    name = "optimize_lib",
    tool = ":matchcompiler",
    deps = [":cppcheck"]
)

I have been able to get other iterations of this tule to print the files, etc - and it get to "Made it here" - but I get no python error, nothing.  It is like it skips over the ctx.actions.run part.
Running with bazel build //:optimize_lib prints:
└┌(%:~/Downloads/cppcheck-2.14.2)┌- bazel build //:optimize_lib              
DEBUG: /home/me/Downloads/cppcheck-2.14.2/macros.bzl:99:10: Made it here.

and I can print the arguments:
DEBUG: /home/me/Downloads/cppcheck-2.14.2/macros.bzl:92:10: --read-dir=lib --write-dir=build vfvalue.cpp valueflow.cpp utils.cpp tokenlist.cpp tokenize.cpp token.cpp timer.cpp templatesimplifier.cpp symboldatabase.cpp suppressions.cpp summaries.cpp settings.cpp reverseanalyzer.cpp programmemory.cpp preprocessor.cpp platform.cpp pathmatch.cpp pathanalysis.cpp path.cpp mathlib.cpp library.cpp keywords.cpp infer.cpp importproject.cpp fwdanalysis.cpp forwardanalyzer.cpp errortypes.cpp errorlogger.cpp ctu.cpp cppcheck.cpp color.cpp clangimport.cpp checkvaarg.cpp checkunusedvar.cpp checkunusedfunctions.cpp checkuninitvar.cpp checktype.cpp checkstring.cpp checkstl.cpp checksizeof.cpp checkpostfixoperator.cpp checkother.cpp checknullpointer.cpp checkmemoryleak.cpp checkleakautovar.cpp checkio.cpp checkinternal.cpp checkfunctions.cpp checkexceptionsafety.cpp checkersreport.cpp checkers.cpp checkcondition.cpp checkclass.cpp checkbufferoverrun.cpp checkboost.cpp checkbool.cpp checkautovariables.cpp checkassert.cpp check64bit.cpp check.cpp astutils.cpp analyzerinfo.cpp addoninfo.cpp

What am I missing?

Of course, as soon as I post this - I figured out the piece I was missing:
print("Made it here")
return [DefaultInfo(files = depset(outputs))]

At least - it runs the python file now.
